# Encoding Webm video with VP9 codec with ffmpeg

Tags: html, ffmpeg, webm, vp9

I am trying to encode a Webm video for embedding in  HTML5 tag. According to information from Wikipedia and other places, Chrome and Firefox should support Webm with both VP9 and VP9 codecs.

When I encode the vide with the VP8 codec, the video plays fine in both browsers. Here is the ffmpeg command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -f webm -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -b:v 10M -crf 50 -y result.webm
```

However, I wanted to use VP9 instead of VP8 to reduce the file size. So I changed the command to use the VP9 codec:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -f webm -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -acodec libvorbis -b:v 10M -crf 50 -y result.webm
```

The output video file is produced, but it doesn't play both in Chrome and FireFox. The only thing I changed was the "vcodec" option.

So my question is, how can I encode Webm video with VP9 codec using ffmpeg so that it is playable in Web browsers?

Comment: Which browser versions?

Comment: Chrome 59.0.3071.115, FireFox 54.0